# How to avoid color inconsistency in transfering graphics between R / ggplot, Microsoft Office, and G-Suite?

Tags: r, ggplot2, google-sheets, svg, powerpoint

As part of my job, I sometimes make charts or tables in `ggplot2` to eventually be displayed in reports in G-Suite (generally Google Slides or Google Sheets). The standard rendering / transfering method we've used is a bit indirect: I export the graphics to a Microsoft PowerPoint file using the `svg()` function, and then the person creating the report copies the vector into Google Slides or Sheets. Someone recently noticed that the colors they see at the end in G-Suite are very slightly different than the HEX codes they originally gave me; not night and day difference, but you can notice if you look closely.

I confirmed that the colors look fine in the original PowerPoints, so my suspicion is that this is something getting lost in translation between Office and G-Suite. Has anybody had a problem like this and found a way to get around this? If possible, I'd prefer solutions that don't involve converting the graphics to an image and uploading it that way (the people creating the reports like the ability to edit text if possible, so vectorized graphics are ideal).

Comment: Can you include a simple example that demonstrates this issue? It will be easier to confirm which step is causing it if we can replicate it.

Comment: Mac or Windows?  It matters.